# user choice for events

Tags: nodes

im creating community event site where i have city and events in that city. i would like to give option for user to select which cities he would like to see the events for. whats the best way to do this? i have created content type of city and events, and using entity referrence to tie events to the city, now im kinda stuck on how do i give a user ability to chose which city/cities he wants to view events for. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you have asked, in the following steps:

1. Create Event content type
2. Create City content type
3. Add field called events in City content type of type Entity Reference (Install and enable the module Entity Reference) - Configure the field to point to Event content type and make it multi-valued
4. Create a View of type page
5. Filter by content type for both ***Event*** and ***City***
6. Create relationship on entity reference field in City content type named events (i.e. A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_events)
7. Select use the relation and make it ***Required*** - require could be useful
8. Save your view, add another filter as follow
9. Filter on content:title field, select the newly created relationship, operator choose either "Is equal to" or "Contains .." and then choose ***Expose*** filter and then
10. Apply
11. Save the view, navigate to the created page, enter the city name and the filter should show you the events that are referenced in that city, see the screenshots below

Event configuration page 
[image]

Events in London
[image]

Events in Paris
[image]

All events 
[image]

The view export code

```
    $view = new view();
$view->name = 'events_by_city';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'events-by-city';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'events-by-city';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'input_required';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['text_input_required_format'] = 'filtered_html';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '50';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Entity Reference: Referencing entity */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_events_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_events_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_events_node']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_events_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_events_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_events_node']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'city' => 'city',
  'event_' => 'event_',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_events_node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['label'] = 'Type city name to show events taking place';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'city' => 'city',
  'event_' => 'event_',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_events_node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['label'] = 'Enter city name to show events';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'Events by city';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'events-by-city';
```

You can also find out how to use contextual filters. I guess this tutorial can give you more ideas http://torontowebsitedeveloper.com/drupal-video-tutorials/drupal-7-node-reference-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need the [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

I haven't used it with entity reference before, but I think you will need to set up a new view that displays events and use the *relationship* settings to link them to your city nodes.

If you don't actually need the cities to be nodes, you could make them a taxonomy instead which is much simpler to create a view for because you can make a field on your event that directly references the taxonomy.

Finally, to 'allow the user to choose' anything you need [exposed filters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Yk6rre3vi8) in your view.